Why do they use 拜会?
I read the news report that the president of a local chamber of commerce paid a visit to an ambassador of a Southeast Asian nation in Beijing “XX会长在北京拜会了XX驻华大使".
Does that mean the guy was on his knees during the interview as we can see today in countries like Thailand and Cambodia? Isn't it funny?

There are some basic misconceptions here. 拜会 is neutral word that doesn't demean any of the individuals involved. Sohu for instance, mentions that, "“拜会”可用于晚辈对上辈的会见，但用于平辈或平级的会晤较多，如国家主席出访某国时到总统府拜会了该国总统。这种情况下，本国记者用“拜会”来报道，也不会降低主席的身份和有损国格。假如对方是位部长，则不会登门去会见他，也不会用“拜会”来报道。"

拜 does not have connotations of kneeling or prostrating or even bowing, although such may be added (e.g. 跪拜); although it may have connections to the worship of deities (拜神), these can also be specified more clearly (e.g. 敬拜, 崇拜). Also compare 拜謁, 拜見 for such lexical honorifics.

You also need to remember cultural differences. Chinese traditionally place oneself at a slightly lower position as a token of deference, for example 晚生、後學、在下、不才

@fatpenguin You are right, my teacher also told me some other phrases to support your point, like 贱内 犬子 奴才 拙作, do you agree with him?

I wouldn't say it's right or wrong, otherwise we will end up in a tangent. It's just how the culture is.

拜会: 拜访会见——今多用于外交上的正式访问
2010年3月31日，驻英国大使刘晓明拜会英国前首相托尼·布莱尔。
On the 31st March 2010, the ambassador in Great Britain, Liu Xiaoming, visited former Prime Minister Tony Blair.
It's just a polite way of saying visit, especially in diplomatic circles.
Nobody is going to get on their knees to the greatest liar in modern British politics!

It is OK when you personally say to a third party to show your respect, but I don't understand why news media uses such a word of inequality in reporting.

There is nothing unequal about 拜会

You can interpret 拜会 as "formally meet." 会见 maybe formal or informal, but 拜会 is always formal.

拜會(meet) is a more respectful word for 會面(meet). It is a figure of speech and doesn't mean you physically get on your hands and knees to worship when you meet someone
Since people only 拜(worship) deities or someone in a higher social class than themselves, the word 拜 has become a humble/ polite prefix.
見 = to see/ to meet -->  拜見 =  humblely/ respectfully see/meet someone
訪 = to visit -->  拜訪 = humbly/ respectfully visit the host
讀 = to read -->  拜讀 = humbly/ respectfully read the author's work
謝 = thanks -->  拜謝 = humbly/ respectfully thanks
會 = meet -->  拜會 = humbly/ respectfully meet someone

Why do they use 拜会?

It would be best to be respectful when meeting someone of a higher social status.
When you visit your uncle, you are 拜訪 (humbly visiting)him; When your uncle comes to see you, he is 探訪(visiting) you

But in real life, people have to be on their knees that are bent and twisted when meeting the royal family, like in Thailand and Cambodia, and their gesture made  on the ground looks like a torture, I have seen the pictures

@NanningYouth not sure about your definition of torture here.  looks 1000x more comfortable than regular kneeling done in tea ceremony or martial arts or other formal kneeling-- which makes sense, if they are holding the pose for really extended periods of time.

@zagrycha Whether it is comfortable or not, you can try that for yourself to "enjoy" that special experience. LOL. If it was a good practice, I guess people were still doing it in China. As the small countries of the Southeast Asia used to be the colony-like land to the old dynasties of China, their customs and culture were transferred from the mainland.

@NanningYouth rest assured I did not make my comment in vain, I have kneeled plenty for formality, whether japanese tea ceremony, chinese gongfu, or martial arts.  and your legs are completely numb and in pain about 10-15 minutes in, max.  the half laying down pose they are doing absolutely looks kore comfortable physically speaking ((if you emotionally feel its uncomfortable thats fine but a completely seperate concept)).

"拜" does not link to kneeling directly, rather, it refers to a pose that shows respect/humility towards the higher-ups, whether the pose is bowing(鞠躬), kneeling(下跪), or simply putting palms together(雙掌合十).
The compound word "拜會" carries the root attitude of "拜", and means "respectfully/humbly to meet with...". The term specifically linked to "the pose of kneeling" is "跪拜".
